# Getting TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46: when uploading an image using Elfinder

Tags: laravel-5, ckeditor, elfinder

Im using Laravel 5 with CKEditor and [Elfinder](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder) to create a WYSIWYG editor in a CMS. Ive got the file browser up and running, but i cant get the file upload to work. I have the upload tab, but when I click Send to Server I get the following:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

I removed verifyCsrf from Kernel.php which removed that error specifically. It did, throw a new exception, but I'll save that for a future question. Ultimately, I dont want to disable csrf across the board just for image uploads. So I thought I could exclude the routes:

**/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:**

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'elfinder/*'
    ];
```

I am assuming all elfinder routes run under a elfinder prefix, although I don't have any evidence to back this up. The documentation is not too clear on the routes that run during upload. Welp....this doesn't work either.

So a followup: Is this the right direction? Anyone know the exact routes that get run on Elfinder?

**UPDATE 2**

Using this [article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes) I created my own VerifyCsrfTokenCustom class and was able to disable CSRF on Elfinder only. There seems to be a routing issue for a get/post route, but I think that should be a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is CSRF protection. You can either pass token to Ckeditor or in `app\Http\Kernel.php` you might comment line with `VerifyCsrfToken` in `$middleware` property and this way you will turn off CSRF protection.

Comment: I would rather not turn off CSRF. Would the placeholder plugin be the direction to go for this?

Comment: Looking at the placeholder plugin, it doesn't seem to be what I need. I would think an image upload in an editor would be pretty straightforward.